# ajax não está retornando sucesso no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Olá, estou conhecendo este framework agora. Estou tentando mandar ajax via post e ver se ele retorna algo, porém não deu certo, segue o problema abaixo:

```
 $("#modal-comentario").on("click", function(){
        var get_id = $(this).data("obs-id");
        $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
                },
                url: "{{ URL::to('lista-contatos/update') }}",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    "id": get_id
                },
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
        });
 });
```

ContatoController

```
public function update(Request $request){
    echo "teste";
}
```

Route

```
Route::post('/lista-contatos/update',
       ['as' => 'lista-contatos', 
        'uses' => 'ContatoController@update']);
```

Não está gerando o `alert(result)` quando clico no botão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Laravel é `return` dentro do método, então, troque `echo` por `return`:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    return "teste";
}
```

Se a ***informação*** realmente foi enviada para o `Controller` isso vai resolver.

Acabei achando outro problema o seu `Route` deixe assim:

```
Route::post('/lista-contatos/update',[
        'as' => 'lista-contatos', 
        'uses' => 'ContatoController@update'
]);
```

retire a `function(){}`, só é colocado quando você não tem um `Controller` declarado.

#### Exemplo funcional:

---

**Pagina:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel - Test</title>
    {{ Html::script('js/jquery.v1.11.0.js') }}
</head>
<body>
        {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'test.update', 'role'=>'form', 'id' =>'form1','name' =>'form1' )) }}
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="1" />
            <button type="button" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
        {{ Form::close() }}
        <script>
            $("#btnEnviar").on("click", function(){
                var get_id    = $("#id").val();
                var get_token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': get_token
                    },
                    url: "{{ URL::to('test/update') }}",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        "id": get_id
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log(result); //debug
                        alert(result.id);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Route (Rota)**

```
Route::post('/test/update', array(
       'before' => 'csrf', 
       'as' => 'test.update', 
       'uses' => 'TestController@update')
);
```

---

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;


class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        return response()
             ->json(['id' => (int)$request->get('id')]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiz essas modificações e continua não aparecendo o alerta. Fiz um teste aqui mudando a rota post para get e acessei a url para ver se a string está sendo printada e foi printada. Esquisito.

Comment: @denali pode ser várias coisas, Route iguais, pode ser configuração errada. Se fez um debug pelo navegador, aperte F12 em console e executa isso para você ter uma idéia. Outra coisa depois dessa linha `var get_id = $(this).data("obs-id");` dê um console.log(get_id). tem vários probleminhas no seu código um desses pode conter problemas!

Comment: @denali eu fiz um exemplo funcional, simples que servirá de auxilio para a sua solução. é bem parecido, espero que aproveite o máximo. Se pode pegar esse código e carregar em um controller separado para teste.