# Update com ajax em laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

Tenho um projeto em `Laravel` e quero fazer com que quando o usuário digite alguma coisa no campo de texto, ao tirar o foco do campo ele faça uma requisição `ajax` para o servidor para atualizar a informação. Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $('#table-fases tbody tr td > input').on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var titulo = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/fases/editar',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: id, titulo: titulo, _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}'},

            success: function(response) {
                $('#edit-success').append("<div class='alert alert-success'>
                   <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'
                                                     aria-label='Close'>
                   <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                   </button><strong>Fase editada.</strong></div>");
            } 
        });  
    });
```

**Rota:**

```
Route::post('/fases/editar', 'FasesController@update');
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\FaseRequest;
use App\Pedido;
use App\Fase;
use Session;

class FasesController extends Controller {

    public function index($pedido_id, $codigo) {
        $tituloPedido = Pedido::find($pedido_id);
        $fases = Fase::getFasesPedido($pedido_id);
        return view('fases.index', compact('codigo', 'pedido_id', 'fases', 'tituloPedido'));
    }

    public function salvar(FaseRequest $request) {
        $dados = $request->all();
        $codigo = $dados['codigo'];
        unset($dados['codigo']);

        $fase = new Fase($dados);

        if($fase->save()) {
            Session::flash('success', 'Fase cadastrada com sucesso.');
            return redirect('/pedido/fases/' . $dados['pedido_id'] .  '/' . $codigo);
        }
        else {
            Session::flash('error', 'Problemas ao cadastrar fase. Tente novamente.');
            return redirect('/pedido/fases/' . $dados['pedido_id'] .  '/' . $codigo);   
        }
    }

    public function update(Request $request) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization");

        $dados = $request->all();

        $fase = Fase::find($dados['id']);

        if($fase->update($dados)) {
            return "success";
        }
    }

    public function delete($id, $pedido_id, $codigo) {
        $fase = Fase::find($id);

        if($fase->delete()) {
            Session::flash('success', 'Fase excluída com sucesso.');
            return redirect('/pedido/fases/' . $pedido_id .  '/' . $codigo);    
        }
        else {
            Session::flash('error', 'Problemas ao excluir fase. Tente novamente.');
            return redirect('/pedido/fases/' . $pedido_id .  '/' . $codigo);
        }
    }

    public function listar_andamento($codigo) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization");

        $existeCodigo = Fase::existeCodigo($codigo);

        if(empty($existeCodigo)) {
            return 'error';
        }
        else {
            $fases = Fase::getFasesApi($codigo);
            return response()->json($fases);
        }
    }
}
```

Mas quando acesso minha rota no navegador aparace o erro:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

Comment: Coloque o controller

Comment: Coloquei o conteúdo do controller.

Comment: Tem que ser completo

Comment: Coloquei o controller todo.

Comment: E ai deu certo?

Comment: Opa. Bom dia! Desculpa a demora cara. Deu certo sim. Obrigado :)

Comment: Se puder assinale como resposta do pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de acessar a rota pelo navegador é que o método configurado na rota só serve para o verb `POST`, mas, existe a forma aonde um método responda a mais `Verb` configurado ou até a todos, ***exemplo***:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});
```

***no seu caso***:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/fases/editar', 'FasesController@update');
```

---

Se quiser que esse método responda a todos os `Verbs`, ***exemplo***:

```
Route::any('foo', function () {
    //
});
```

***no seu caso***:

```
Route::any('/fases/editar', 'FasesController@update');
```

com essa mudança(s) na configuração os problemas de método não aceito (`MethodNotAllowedHttpException`) não existiram mais.

***Observação:*** os `headers` nos métodos são desnecessário, tem além da parte de rotas outros problemas no seu código.

***Links relacionados:***

- [Problemas ao deletar via ajax com laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170557/problemas-ao-deletar-via-ajax-com-laravel/170558#170558)
- [ajax não está retornando sucesso no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152666/ajax-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-retornando-sucesso-no-laravel/152668#152668)
- [Recebendo uma requisição ajax com laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160038/recebendo-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-com-laravel/160045#160045)
- [Requisição Ajax com Laravel 5.4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266094/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-com-laravel-5-4/266166#266166)

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Laravel - Basic Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#basic-routing)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Se tu acessares a rota apartir do navegador dará esse erro porque a rota é do tipo "POST" e tu está tentando acessar via "GET". Se acessares pelo ajax ali vai ocorrer tudo bem.

Pode usar um programa chamado POSTMAN para testar tuas rotas. Ele é muito bom.